# Javascript turns array into string

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I'm rewriting some Python code in javascript and I'm running into something strange. I'm sure I'm overlooking something stupid, but it appears that it's returning a comma-separated string where I expect an array.

**python:**

```
    triples = [('one', 'two', 'three'), (...), ... ]
    for w1, w2, w3 in triples:
        key = (w1, w2)
        if key in self.cache:
            self.cache[key].append(w3)
        else:
            self.cache[key] = [w3]
```

**returns:**

```
('of', 'Thee,'): ['Sailing', 'Light'], 
('meat', 'within'): ['is'],
```

**javascript:**

```
        for (var i=0; i<=triples.length; i++) {

        if (triples[i]) {
        var key = [triples[i][0], triples[i][1]];
        if (key in this.cache) {
            this.cache[key].push(triples[i][2]);

        } else {
            this.cache[key] = [];
            this.cache[key].push(triples[i][2]);
        }
    }
    }
```

**returns:**

```
 'you,estimated,': [ 'and', 'and' ],
  'estimated,,and': [ 'far', 'far' ],
```

Comment: You get an Object with your function, and objects can't have arrays as key. You can use a Map() though

Comment: This piece of code relies on having arrays as keys...does that mean this just can't be done in javascript?

Comment: It can be done, but you'd have to make your object a Map.

Comment: I've been trying to implement this but can't get around ReferenceError: Map() is not defined